# Draw a box on an image, javascript only?

Tags: javascript

What i want to do is have a user upload his image. When its complete it will display the image on the same page w/o refreshing. Here is the part i need to figure out, how do i have the user select a box in the image? so i can crop it when the user is done? (using ImageMagick).

If possible i would like a border for the user to stretch to edit the width and height. Then click within the rect to move around.

Answer (score 5):

There's a ton of ways; including several pre-written plugins available through the web.

Are you using any frameworks?

Of the below, I've used Jcrop and Lasso.Crop and they've both worked out well.  Haven't tried the others.

Here's a non-exhaustive listing:

**Pure Javascript**

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=image-crop

**jQuery**

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

**MooTools**

http://www.nwhite.net/2009/02/25/lassocrop-preview/

**Prototype**

http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/